# Does Dynamodb support Groupby/ Aggregations directly?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to Dynamodb and have a requirement of grouping the documents on the basis of a certain condition before performing other operations.

From what i could read on the internet, i figured out that there is no direct way to group dynamodb documents.

Can anyone confirm if thats true of help out with a solution if that is not the case?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon DynamoDB is a NoSQL database, so you won't find standard SQL capabilities like `group by` and `average()`.

There is, however, the ability to `filter` results, so you will only receive results that match your criteria. It is then the responsibility of the calling app to perform grouping and aggregations.

It's really a trade-off between the flexibility of SQL and the sheer speed of NoSQL. Plus, in the case of DynamoDB, the benefit of data being stored in three facilities to improve durability and availability.

Comment: I would disagree with your statement that NOSQL db's dont support grouping and other similar functions. In fact NOSQL db's like Elasticsearch and Mongodb have all these functionalities and I have been using them extensively.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm not familiar with those other NoSQL databases.